# single and long press not working after implementing onclick listener for imageButton in listView On android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-event

I have List view on android with [TextView TextView ImageButton]. i implement the list view by using ArrayAdapter. as per my requirement i need single and long press event for list view,so that i use **registerForContextMenu(getListView())** for long press and for single press i use **onListItemClick**. **this was working fine.** after that additionally i need onClick event for imageButton on list view and implemented onclick for the imageButton.

***Now my problem is the single press event and long press event is not working after implementing onClick listener for the imageButton on listView.But ImageButton onClick listener is working fine.***

i add the property **android:focusable="false"** to the imageButton but it is not help to me.

How do i get single and long press events with onclick listener for ImageButton?. pleas Help me.

group.xml:

```
......
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
.....
```

group_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        ......
        android:focusable="false" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/group_row_gadd"
        .....
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/add" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_row_grow"
        ....
        android:focusable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my arrayadapter class:

```
public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener{
    ....    

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false);

        name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.group_row_gname);
        number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.group_row_grow);
        add = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.group_row_gadd);
        add.setTag(position);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rowView;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("onclick", "onclick");
        Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.group_row_gadd:

            break;
        }

    }

}
```

mainclass:

```
public class Group extends ListActivity{
    .....   
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.group);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        .....   
    }// OnCreate End

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        .....
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.group_edit_remove, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        .....
        return false;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also need to set `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to your view elements in **group_row.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Because ImageButton can't get focus.  Set OnItemClickListener on  ListView, item of ListView will  be its first priority to get focus .So when you click the ImageButton, it will not work.You can modify your GroupAdapter.

Comment: please explain me. what to modify the adapter class?

Comment: i have onItemClickListener. please see edited question. please help me.